# what determines the memory model?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

Specifically this question is about flat and segmented model in real mode. I am reading a book on assembly which mentions that on DOS the COM files use flat memory model and EXE files use segmented memory model. However I am not understanding what tells DOS which memory model to use. I am asking this question because I am reading about bootloaders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COM files used a "flat memory model" in the sense that the segment registers were alll set by DOS when the program was loaded to point to the same segment, and all the code and pointers were, by convention, relative to that one value in the segment registers.

The EXE file format, on the other hand, allows for segments to be loaded at different offsets. DOS wouldn't set the segment registers to default values; that was up to the code itself. 16-bit EXE code is a lot more complex because the code has to manage segment registers.

Nowadays a lot of EXE code more or less ignores segment registers again; 32 or 64-bit registers don't need to be added to a segment register to generate a usable address.

Comment: Could  you please tell what made the DOS set the segment registers in case of COM files and leave them in case of EXE files ?

Comment: What made DOS do it? That's just what the DOS code did. I'm not sure how to answer your question: the programmers who programmed DOS told it to do that.

Comment: The DOS EXE format does not have any provision for setting registers other than CS:IP and SS:SP. If it had, the programmer would've had to mark the segments for DS and ES in some special way as well and the assembler, compiler and linker would need to support such specially marked segments in a special way. Perhaps, it was decided that wasn't worth it. After all, formally, your segmented program doesn't have to have any data segment. The bare minimum is the code and stack segments.

Comment: Actually what I meant to ask is that how does DOS decide whether it has to set the segment registers or not. By looking at the file extension or header ?

Comment: DOS placed an enormous amount of importance on file names. The three letter extension alone determined whether a file was a COM program, an EXE program, or some kind of data. The EXE format includes a "magic number", but I'm pretty sure DOS didn't even look at it.

Comment: The EXE file header contains the CS:IP and SS:SP values that DOS will set before executing the file. The code in the EXE will then set DS and ES if and as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The COM and EXE executables had their memory requirements in a file header: [EXE header](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/) and [COM (MS-DOS) header](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files#MS-DOS_header). If the program requires < 64KB, use the flat space, if > 64KB, use segmented memory.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in DOS that can stop COM file from using segmented memory model, since DOS had no memory management policy enforced on it's applications.

You can read wikipedia entry about [COM files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file), it gives an insight into these old matters.