# MS-DOS, what determines the memory model selection

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture, dos, memory-model

In this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#Memory_models) we can see that 16 Bits systems have different memory models.

Through that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778425/what-determines-the-memory-model) we know that COM application always uses the `Tiny Model` (all segments are in the same one) but for the other executables what make the operating system uses one model or another?

I did not see in the MS-DOS Header any flag that would help for a choice so how does MS-DOS determines what memory model to use?

Comment: I don't understand -- your question is perfectly answered in the answer you cite. DOS uses the flat memory model for executables in the COM format, and a segmented one when it detects an EXE format. it's what it does. Even your question title is nearly identical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what determines the memory model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778425/what-determines-the-memory-model)

Comment: Maybe you did not read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778425/what-determines-the-memory-model#comment12449647_9778511) comment? Basically, the file ending determines what DOS does.

Comment: The extension allows the OS to determine whether it a COM or DOS program and since COM programs are small by nature, they use the Tiny Model.
Okay but in the case of a DOS program, what makes the OS choose between one of the six model available?
That being said, the i486's answer may indicate that it's not related to the OS but the compiler.

Comment: Read the answers you cite! **It's not the job of the OS. The program is free to program the memory model defining registers at its own will**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection of memory model is necessary as compiler option, not OS related. You can assume that DOS always works with Large memory model (far pointers for CS and DS).

Comment: So from your answer I gather that the memory models are more "human-readable view" of what the compiler generates for the OpCodes rather that something intrinsic to the OS/processor?

If so then how does the processor knows it should rather use `Far Pointer` or `Near Pointer` when the program needs to access the memory?

Comment: The `near` pointer assumes that segment number is already in the segment register (CS for code, DS for data). With `far` pointers you explicitly load `DS`, `ES`, `FS`, etc. with segment number and do the memory access operation. From OS' viewpoint, segment registers always must be loaded for example to call a program (DOS loads it at address 0x0100 in segment 0x1234, then make far CALL to 1234:0100). The same is with data segment of program - there is no (or little) chance for a DOS program to use the same segment like current OS data segment. In other words, DOS has to load `DS` register.

Comment: PS: `far` calls or `far` data pointers are like global addresses, and `near` pointers are local for DOS program. If the program works with large number of data it uses corresponding memory model in which all data pointers are `far` (i.e. more bytes to encode, slower execution but it has more than 64K memory).